# Recycler Search view gives for filter method and app get closed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview, addtextchangedlistener

I want to search items in [recyclerview](/questions/tagged/recyclerview). I am using [addtextchangedlistener](/questions/tagged/addtextchangedlistener) method for  searching. When I start typing in [edittext](/questions/tagged/edittext) to search an item instead of giving me the filtered results the app get closed and I got the error as

```
12-27 11:29:04.375 18962-18962/com.example.satyabhai.restaurant E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-27 11:31:17.932 18962-18962/com.example.satyabhai.restaurant E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.satyabhai.restaurant, PID: 18962
                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase()' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at com.example.satyabhai.restaurant.CurrentStatus.filter(CurrentStatus.java:121)
                                                                                      at com.example.satyabhai.restaurant.CurrentStatus.access$000(CurrentStatus.java:40)
                                                                                      at com.example.satyabhai.restaurant.CurrentStatus$1.afterTextChanged(CurrentStatus.java:95)
```

This is code for my [edittext](/questions/tagged/edittext) search

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                filter(s.toString());
        }
```

This is code for my Filter method

```
private void filter(String s) {
        ArrayList<CurrentEntry> temp=new ArrayList<>();
        for(CurrentEntry d: current)
        {
            if(d.getName().toLowerCase().contains(s)||d.getNo().toLowerCase().contains(s)||d.getPeople().toLowerCase().contains(s)||d.getEstimate().toLowerCase().contains(s));
            {
                temp.add(d);
            }

        }
        adapt.updateList(temp);
    }
```

This is code for UpdateList

```
 public void updateList(ArrayList<CurrentEntry> temp)
    {
       this.listItems=temp;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

This  is MainActivity code for setting [recyclerview](/questions/tagged/recyclerview)

```
 RecyclerView recyclerView;
    NewAdapter adapt;
    private ArrayList<CurrentEntry> current;
    String userUrl;
    String second_req="second_req";
    EditText search;

    public CurrentStatus() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.current_status,container,false);
        FloatingActionButton fab=(FloatingActionButton)v.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        current=new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
      search=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.search);
```

This line is gettting Issue

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(d.getName())|| !TextUtils.isEmpty(d.getPeople())||!TextUtils.isEmpty(d.getNo())|| !TextUtils.isEmpty(d.getEstimate())) {
                if (d.getName().toLowerCase().contains(s) || d.getNo().toLowerCase().contains(s) || d.getPeople().toLowerCase().contains(s) || d.getEstimate().toLowerCase().contains(s));
                {
                    temp.add(d);
                }
```

This is code for Adapter

```
public class NewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

     ArrayList<CurrentEntry> listItems;
     Context context;

    public NewAdapter (ArrayList<CurrentEntry> listItems, Context context) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void updateList(ArrayList<CurrentEntry> temp)
    {
       this.listItems=temp;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_card,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
           CurrentEntry current=listItems.get(position);
           holder.number.setText(current.getNo());
           holder.Name.setText(current.getName());
           holder.People.setText(current.getPeople());
           holder.Estimate.setText(current.getEstimate());
          // holder.Foodie.setText(current.getFoodie());
    }



    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView number;
        TextView Name ;
        TextView People;
        TextView Estimate;
     //   TextView Foodie;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            number=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.no);
            Name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            People=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.people);
            Estimate=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.estimate);
          //  Foodie=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodie);

        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recyclerview No adapter attached; skipping layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: d.getName() giving null value. Debug your code when you are adding value in current.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1.Before converting string to `toLowerCase` check that string is available or not tp avoid this issue

```
    private void filter(String s) {
        ArrayList<CurrentEntry> temp=new ArrayList<>();
        for(CurrentEntry d: current)
        {

            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(d.getName())&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(d.getNo())&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(d.getPeople())&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(d.getEstimate()))
            {
                if(d.getName().toLowerCase().contains(s)||d.getNo().toLowerCase().contains(s)||d.getPeople().toLowerCase().contains(s)||d.getEstimate().toLowerCase().contains(s));
                {
                    temp.add(d);
                }
            }
            else {
                //String is empty
            }

        }
        adapt.updateList(temp);
    }
```

2.`recyclerview No adapter attached; skipping layout` for this error. Add layout manager for your `recycleview`

```
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    list.setLayoutManager(llm);
    list.setAdapter( adapter );
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is the value in d.getName() ?

Comment: It is simply a String

Comment: String is ok value is there or null?

Comment: You have to check not only `d.getName()`,`d.getNo()`,`d.getPeople()`,`d.getEstimate() ` these four things null check then try to convert as toLowerCase()

Comment: When I add all the fields it is giving me error that  Operator '||' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'java.lang.String

Comment: Which line are getting this issue

Comment: I have add in my Question

Comment: you should not use || because inside your block other values also your checking so try to use && all values should not empty else check specific field

Comment: Still issue is there?

Comment: Yes. Item is  not getting search. when I type something all records get disappear and no item in recycler view is filtered

Comment: Can you add your complete adapter code and activity code i will tell you how to fix